# Why would App Store Connect say "Newer Build Available" when there isn't?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I made a new build of my app (version 2.2 build 11) and uploaded to App Store Connect.

Then I used "(+) Version or platform" to prepare version 2.2 for submission. When I press "Submit for Review", I get a warning:

> Newer Build Available
>
> Are you sure you want to submit this build for review? A newer build of your app is available. To submit the newer build, delete this earlier build and resubmit.

The currently released version of the app is 2.1. The "Activity" tab of App Store Connect only shows this build (11) for version 2.2. Build 10 was version 2.1.

What does this error actually mean, and how am I meant to resolve it? The obvious thing is to try deleting this build and resubmitting it, but I'd like to understand more about the error, especially if it turns out deleting and resubmitting doesn't help (haven't tried yet).

Comment: Have checked your app activity section where all the builds are shown version-wise.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Yup, tried to say that above. The "Activity" tab only shows this build for this version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved it.

As an infrequent iOS developer, I thought that specifying the version number after hitting "(+) Version or platform" would be enough. But I missed actually choosing the build far down in the submission form.

Presumably it defaults to the previously submitted build, which in this case would be 2.1 build 10, causing the error.

So the error message could have been better, but it was ultimately something I missed.

Comment: In my case, the new release build was still "Processing" and not available. Waiting until it finished processing then selecting per this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the older build and upload a new one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check `Activity` tab, if it says 'Processing` than you will not be able to add the build to the release, and you will get this error message.

Wait for about 10, minutes for it to complete, add your build to the release, and you are good to go.

[image]